# Reading a Multi-Level JSON file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, multi-level

I have been assigned a project and received a multi-level JSON file to read the data from.
I need to do this using jQuery.
This is my first time dealing with JSON files so a good explanation can help. I couldn't find a good answer anywhere since most jQuery + JSON tutorials are for very very very basic data structure.

This is the data in my JASON file:
http://cl.ly/0w19091v290i3p402N0B

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hmm, JASON is usually a difficult guy to deal with... however, if you just tell jQuery.get to "use JSON" then you get back the JSON-already-turned-into the corresponding JS objects: what is the question, then?

Comment: The beauty of it is that everything works exactly as it does for simple objects. `obj["league"][0]["event"][0]["participant"][0]["name"]==="Alcorcon"`

Comment: Haha I'm sorry I didn't notice I wrote "JASON". anyway, I couldn't really understand what to do with it. what I'm trying to do is present the data inside divs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get the JSON data. Which, as stated, get's the data via ajax and converts the JSON into a javascript object.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I present it though? can I get some code example I could start with?

Comment: @yeahmeknows just like you'd present any other string. hard to know what you need exactly but here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Frd6Z/

Answer (score 0):

this would be response from ajax

```
      success: function (doc) {                        
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(doc);
                    $(obj.league).each(function () {   // to get everything in league  
                     ...
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andy has already mentioned, you can use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get the data via AJAX and convert it into javascript objects. So, probably you'll get a collection of javascript objects which you need to display in a table-like visual structure. For that, you can check out [JTemplates](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jTemplates).